# Android app coming up with black screen

Tags: android

I am writing an app, but when I run it, it  is coming up with a black screen. I have debugged and debugged and cannot find what is going wrong. Thanks is advance for any and all help. I am trying to write a hangman game in Hebrew.
Here is the code:

```
public class The_game extends AppCompatActivity  {
    boolean pressed = false;
    int mistakes;
    TextView score, categ, show;
    Button a,b,g,d,h,v,z,ch,t,y,c,l,m,n,s,ah,p,tz,k,r,sh,th,contin;
    boolean ai=true,bi=true,gi=true,di=true,hi=true,vi=true,zi=true,chi=true,ti=true,yi=true,ci=true,li=true,mi=true,ni=true,si=true,ahi=true,pi=true,tzi=true,ki=true,ri=true,shi=true,thi=true;
    private ImageView hangman;
    private points po=new points();
    private String unknown="";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.the_game);
        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
        g = (Button) findViewById(R.id.g);
        d = (Button) findViewById(R.id.d);
        h = (Button) findViewById(R.id.h);
        v = (Button) findViewById(R.id.v);
        z = (Button) findViewById(R.id.z);
        ch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ch);
        t = (Button) findViewById(R.id.t);
        y = (Button) findViewById(R.id.y);
        c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.c);
        l = (Button) findViewById(R.id.l);
        m = (Button) findViewById(R.id.m);
        n = (Button) findViewById(R.id.n);
        s = (Button) findViewById(R.id.s);
        ah = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ah);
        p = (Button) findViewById(R.id.p);
        tz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tz);
        k = (Button) findViewById(R.id.k);
        r = (Button) findViewById(R.id.r);
        sh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sh);
        th = (Button) findViewById(R.id.th);
        contin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contin);
        categ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.categ);
        show = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show);
        hangman=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hangman);

        contin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent next=new Intent(The_game.this,EnterName.class);
                next.putExtra("points", po.getPoints());
                startActivity(next);
            }
        });
        score.setText(Integer.toString(po.getPoints()));
        newGame();
    }

    public void newGame() {
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);
            int yellow = 15899407;
            final int afor = 428720268;
            a.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            b.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            g.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            d.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            h.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            a.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            v.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            z.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            ch.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            t.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            y.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            c.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            l.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            m.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            n.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            s.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            ah.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            p.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            tz.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            k.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            sh.setBackgroundColor(yellow);
            th.setBackgroundColor(yellow);

            hangman.setImageResource(R.drawable.mzer);
            String[] word = db.getWord();
            mistakes = 0;
            categ.setText(word[1]);
            unknown = "";
            final String text = word[0];
            final int number = text.length();
            int spaces=0;

            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                if (text.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                    unknown=unknown+'_';
             }
                else  {
                    unknown=unknown+'-';
                    spaces++;
            }
        }
        show.setText(unknown);

            while (7 > mistakes) {
                int q = number-spaces;
                for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                    if ((text.charAt(i) != '_')&&(text.charAt(i) != '-')) {
                        q--;
                    }
                }
                if (q == 0) {
                    score.setText(Integer.toString(po.addPoints()));
                    newGame();
                }
                show.setText(unknown);


                if (mistakes == 1) {
                    hangman.setImageResource(R.drawable.mone);
                }
                if (mistakes == 2) {
                    hangman.setImageResource(R.drawable.mtwo);
                }
                if (mistakes == 3) {
                    hangman.setImageResource(R.drawable.mthre);
                }
                if (mistakes == 4) {
                    hangman.setImageResource(R.drawable.mfor);
                }
                if (mistakes == 5) {
                    hangman.setImageResource(R.drawable.mfive);
                }
                if (mistakes == 6) {
                    hangman.setImageResource(R.drawable.msix);
                }

                while (!pressed) {
                a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (ai == true) {
                            pressed = true;
                            String unknown = getUnknown();
                            ai = false;
                            a.setBackgroundColor(10 * afor + 5);
                            boolean f = false;
                            for (int w = 0; w < number; w++) {
                                if (text.charAt(w) == 'א') {
                                    f = true;
                                    po.addPoint();
                                    String part1 = unknown.substring(0, w);
                                    String part2 = unknown.substring(w + 1);
                                    unknown = part1 + 'א' + part2;
                                    show.setText(unknown);
                                }
                            }
                            if (f != true) {
                                mistakes++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

(I deleted 20 almost identical sets of code, one for each of the different Hebrew letters.)

```
   th.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (thi == true) {
                            pressed = true;
                            thi = false;
                            th.setBackgroundColor(10 * afor + 5);
                            String unknown = getUnknown();
                            boolean f = false;
                            for (int w = 0; w < number; w++) {
                                if (text.charAt(w) == 'ת') {
                                    f = true;
                                    po.addPoint();
                                    String part1 = unknown.substring(0, w);
                                    String part2 = unknown.substring(w + 1);
                                    unknown = part1 + 'ת' + part2;
                                    show.setText(unknown);

                                }
                            }
                            if (f != true) {
                                mistakes++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
                pressed=false;
            }
            Intent lose = new Intent(The_game.this, EnterName.class);
            lose.putExtra("points", po.getPoints());
            startActivity(lose);
        }

        //else
            {
                //Toast.makeText(this, "אין לך מילים שהוכנסו. אנא הכנס מילים.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    public String getUnknown() {
        return unknown;
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<RelativeLayout android:background="#ffffff" android:textDirection="rtl" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:text="ת" android:layout_marginStart="16dp" android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" android:id="@+id/th"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="ש" android:layout_marginStart="10dp" android:id="@+id/sh" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/th" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/th"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="ר" android:layout_marginStart="10dp" android:id="@+id/r" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sh" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sh"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="ק" android:layout_marginStart="10dp" android:id="@+id/k" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/r" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/r"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="צ" android:layout_marginStart="10dp" android:id="@+id/tz" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/k" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/k"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="פ" android:layout_marginStart="10dp" android:id="@+id/p" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tz" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tz"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="ע" android:layout_marginStart="10dp" android:id="@+id/ah" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/p" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/p"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="ס" android:layout_marginStart="10dp" android:id="@+id/s" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ah" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ah"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="נ" android:layout_marginBottom="11dp" android:id="@+id/n" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/th" android:layout_above="@+id/th"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="מ" android:id="@+id/m" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/n" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sh"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="ל" android:id="@+id/l" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/m" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/r"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="כ" android:id="@+id/c" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/n" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/k"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="י" android:id="@+id/y" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/c" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tz"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="ט" android:id="@+id/t" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/y" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/p"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="ח" android:id="@+id/ch" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/m" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ah"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="ז" android:id="@+id/z" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ch" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/s"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="ו" android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" android:id="@+id/v" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/m" android:layout_above="@+id/n"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="ה" android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" android:id="@+id/h" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/l" android:layout_above="@+id/n"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="ד" android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" android:id="@+id/d" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/c" android:layout_above="@+id/n"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="ג" android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" android:id="@+id/g" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/y" android:layout_above="@+id/n"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="ב" android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" android:id="@+id/b" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/t" android:layout_above="@+id/n"/>

<Button android:background="#f29b0f" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="א" android:id="@+id/a" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ch" android:layout_below="@+id/hangman"/>

<TextView android:background="#ffffff" android:layout_height="48dp" android:layout_width="83dp" android:textSize="28dp" android:text="" android:id="@+id/score" android:layout_above="@+id/show" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/categ" android:textColor="#020202"/>

<ImageView android:layout_height="35dp" android:layout_width="45dp" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_above="@+id/show" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/score" app:srcCompat="@drawable/cup"/>

<TextView android:textDirection="rtl" android:layout_height="70dp" android:layout_width="240dp" android:textSize="23dp" android:text="קטגוריה" android:id="@+id/categ" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:textColor="#000000" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

<TextView android:layout_height="230dp" android:layout_width="225dp" android:textSize="45dp" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:text="_________-_________" android:id="@+id/show" android:layout_below="@+id/categ" android:textColor="#000000"/>

<ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/hangman" android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/show" android:layout_above="@+id/b" android:layout_below="@+id/categ" app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

<Button android:background="#c40010" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_width="35dp" android:textSize="12dp" android:text="ליציאה" android:id="@+id/contin" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/z" android:layout_below="@+id/hangman"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have any error / warning ?

Comment: Please post the_game file.

Comment: Would you please send `activity_the_game.xml` code?

Comment: I added the XML to my question. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I think you run into an infinite loop in your `newGame()` method, which is called in `onCreate`: `while (!pressed) {` and `pressed` is initialized with `false`. As a matter of fact you should get an ANR.